# How can I use tf.gather to slice values from the first axis?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I would expect the chunk below to return a tensor with shape `(128,64)` or `(1,128,64)`, since I am telling it to gather values from the first axis and I

```
tf.gather(h_states # shape: (3,128,64)
          ,indices # shape: (128), values are integers between 0 and 2
          ,axis = 0
          ,batch_dims=0)
```

Instead it is returning a `(128,128,64)` tensor. What am I doing wrong? How could I actually make it select sub-tensors from the first axis?

Thanks

Comment: You expect to return a tensor with shape (128,64) .Do you want to get one row from your  (3,128,64) tensor ?

Comment: Yes (if "row" refers to the first dimension). I want to get the row that is determined by theindices tensor.

Comment: You can simply  slice the tensor e.g: yourTensor[ indexYouWant  ,  :  ,  :  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the gather method, slice the tensor is very simple .

```
yourTensor[ indexYouWant , : , : ]                 # shape(128,64)
yourTensor[ indexYouWant:indexYouWant+1 , : , : ]  # shape(1,128,64)
```

if you want multiple row (e.g : index 0 and 2),you can use gather method:

```
tf.gather(yourTensor , indices = [0,2] , axis = 0)
```